# Spring MVC: Complex object as parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I started to learn spring boot and I'm faced with problems. I have following code:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getMessageInfo(Message message) {
        return "Id is " + message.getId() + ", message is " + message.getMessage() + ", parameter good is " + message.isGood();
    }
}
```

Class Message:

```
public class Message {
    private String message;
    private int id;
    private boolean good;

    public Message() {}

    public Message(int id) {this.id = id;}

    public Message(String message) {this.message = message;}

    public Message(boolean good) {this.good = good;}

    public Message(String message, boolean good, int id) {
        this.message = message;
        this.good = good;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public boolean isGood() {
        return good;
    }
}
```

And when I try to do something like this:

```
RestTemplate request = new RestTemplate();
String info = request.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/?id=4", String.class);
```

value of `id` is ignored. Same problem appears when I send request with boolean `good` parameter (for example `localhost:8080/?good=true`). It is called the default constructor instead of `Message(boolean)`/`Message(int)`. But when I do something like `localhost:8080/?message=1234` it isn't ignored. Can you explain me what is the problem?

And one more question: can I send instance of class `Message` to `getMessageInfo` in different way than `localhost:8080/?message=1234&good=true&id=145`? If I have more than 3 parameters? For example if class `Message` has 100 parameters?

Comment: You are missing the annotation RequestParam or ModelAttribute, if it's not a typo?

Comment: I wrote `getMessageInfo(@ModelAttribute("message") Message message)` but nothing changed.

Comment: Spring will always invoke the default constructor and for the parameters use the available setters. As you don't have those nothing will ever be passed along from the request. Binding only works with a class that adheres to the java bean specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are trying to deal with a complex object accept your object from a post request.

```
@RequestMapping("/",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String getMessageInfo(@RequestBody Message message) {
    return message;
}
```

in the above code i'm setting `method` attribute to `POST` then it will be called when you are making a `POST` request, and i am using `@RequestBody Message message` inside the method `parameter`. which will convert and form an `Message object` from the incoming `request`, if you dont put `@requestBody` annotation then a Bean will be `injected` to the method by spring instead of forming a one from the request.

you can try this code to make the request

```
    final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/";

    Message message = new Message(1, "Adam",true);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Message result = restTemplate.postForObject( uri, message, Message.class);
```

when making an request create an `Message object` setting each and every field in it, otherwise you will end up in having `Bad request` error.

Comment: The return type of getMessageInfo() should be Message

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, if add smth like this:

```
@ModelAttribute("message")
    public Message getMessage(String message, boolean good, int id){
    return new Message(message, good, id);
}

@RequestMapping("/")
public String getUserInfo(@ModelAttribute("message") Message message) {
    return "Id is " + message.getId() + ", message is " + message.getMessage() + ", parameter good is " + message.isGood();
}
```

all parameters aren't ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,

```
    MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    params.add("id", 1);
    params.add("good", true);
    params.add("message", 1234);
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(params, requestHeaders);


    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Message message= restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/", requestEntity, Message.class);
```

Comment: the problem remains the same, `int` and `boolean` parameters still with default values.

Comment: In **Message** change int to Integer and boolean to Boolean and try.